# Average on concatenated string with some conditions

Tags: r

I wish to average on my concatenated string with some conditions. this is my data:

```
id  path    events

1    a, b    2, 3
2    c, a    3, 4
3    b       5
```

I'd like to take average of rows that **do not** have a particular path, for instance the average of rows who does not have c  (i.e row 1 and 3) is (2 + 3 + 5) /3 = 3.33

and similar for the others so my desired output will be

```
path   avg
a       5
b       3.5
c       3.33
```

before that I tried for not concatenated data and it worked

```
output <- sapply(as.character(unique(df$path)), 
                 function(x) mean(subset(df, !path %in% x)$events))
```

But could not come up with an idea for this situation

This is my data

```
mydata <- data.frame(id =c(1,2,3), 
                     path= c("a,b", "c,a", "b"),
                     events =c (("2,3"), ("3,4"), ("5")))
```

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate_rows` to unnest your data, but I'm not sure I follow your summarization logic.

Comment: @alistaire thank you   (' mtrying that.  my summeriziation logic exemplified above, for instance for c, we put aside the rows that contain c, so we remove row 2 ( which has c) and keep row 1 and 3 and take average of all the events in row  1 and 3 which is 2+3+ 5 / 3 = 3.33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>% separate_rows(path, events, convert = TRUE) %>%    # unnest rows
    group_by(path) %>%    # set grouping
    summarise(avg = mean(.$events[!.$id %in% id]))    # summarize groups

## # A tibble: 3 × 2
##    path      avg
##   <chr>    <dbl>
## 1     a 5.000000
## 2     b 3.500000
## 3     c 3.333333
```

Note the summarization uses `.$[column name]` to refer to the entire column, and just `[column name]` to refer to the values for the group.

Comment: That's odd. Is it giving you an error message? You could actually just use `library(tidyr); library(dplyr)` directly, if you like; those are the only two it uses.

Comment: If your path and events number are not the same in the row you need to modify @alistaire solution and instead of `separate_rows(events,convert = TRUE)` use `separate_rows(path, convert = TRUE) %>% separate_rows(events,convert = TRUE)`

Comment: @alistaire it's weird . finally I successfully installed the package, but your code gives me this error  Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Updated for the data; you can use `id` directly for indexing. Adding one piece at a time, can you tell which function is causing the error?

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now, before that adding row index `df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) ` causing error for me.

Comment: Thanks @kwicher good point, in this  work, they have same number.